# Explaining the derivative in a neural network with one neuron

Tags: python, math, deep-learning, neural-network, derivative

I have a maximal simple neural network with one neuron, in which I do not understand where the definition of `derivative` variable comes from. I understand that it is the derivative, giving me the "slope" of the function, but why exactly `input * clear_error`? The derivative of which original function do we find, and why exactly that one?

```py
weight = 10
goal = 12.9
input = 9

alpha = 0.01

for i in range(20):
    prediction = weight * input
    clear_error = prediction - goal
    sq_error = (prediction - goal) ** 2
    
    derivative = input * clear_error
    weight = weight - (derivative * alpha)
    
    print(f"Error: {sq_error}; Prediction: {prediction}")
```

Comment: The partial derivative is for the weight factor. That this formula, with factors of 2 or 1/2 missing, is the natural form for the gradient can only be seen in more general forms of parametrized functions `y=f(x,w)`.

Comment: Write the weight as `w`, input as `x` and goal as `g`. Then the loss function is `sq_error = (wx - g) ** 2`. The gradient with respect to weight is `d(sq_error) / dw = 2x(w-x)` which is equivalent to `2 * input * clear_error`. So the `derivative` in the code is actually half the real gradient, but being out by a constant factor doesn't matter (you're scaling the gradient by alpha anyway).

Comment: Could you make a drawing of the neural network?

Comment: @slothrop Might as well post that comment as an answer!

Comment: Please note that this is math, not a programming question, so it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the weight as `w`, input as `x`, goal as `g` and loss function (i.e. `sq_error` in the code) as `l`.

Then: `l = (wx - g) ** 2`

What we need for backpropagation is the **gradient of the loss function with respect to weight**, which is `dl / dw = 2x(wx - g)`

...which is equivalent to `2 * input * clear_error`.

So the derivative in the code is actually half the real gradient, but being out by a constant factor doesn't matter (you're scaling the gradient by alpha anyway).

---

*If you want to break the calculation of the derivative down further:*

Write `u = wx - g` so that `l = u**2`

So `du / dw = x` and `dl / du = 2u`

Then `dl / dw = (dl / du) (du / dw)` (chain rule)

i.e. `dl / dw = 2ux = 2x(wx - g)`

`dl / dw = 2 * input * clear_error` in terms of the variables in your code.

So `derivative` is equivalent to `(dl / dw) / 2`.